# Are All Items of a Package Uninstalled when Using Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

This seems like a super simple question with an obvious answer, but I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer.  When uninstalling a package through Homebrew (that was initially installed by Homebrew), are all the items installed always removed?

For instance, if I installed Python3:

```
brew install python3
```

then uninstalled python3:

```
brew uninstall python3
```

Will Homebrew remove every single item it initially installed with the first command?

Comment: Of course not.  Uninstall will remove (and reset) what it is told to do.  You could narrow your question to 'python3' and the answer may be 'Yes'.  Unless the uninstall covers deleting and reverting everything the installer did then no.

Comment: If this is correct, then what is the advantage of using Homebrew to install items if it can't uninstall the same items it installed?